# How to use service in angular.js controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have created the service but i am not getting how use this service in my controller.

```
(function(){
    'use.strict';

    angular
     .module('app.core')
     .factory('shareBtwnCtrlr', shareBtwnCtrlrService);

    /** @ngInject */
    function shareBtwnCtrlrService() {
        shareBtwnCtrlr = function($scope, $rootScope){
            $scope.value = $rootScope.test;
        }
        return shareBtwnCtrlr;
    }
})();
```

In the above code $rootScope.test is coming from one controller and now i have to use this $scope.value in another controller using this service. The another controller is like below

```
(function (){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.product')
        .controller('ProductController', ProductController);

    /** @ngInject */
    //ProductController.$inject = ['$http', '$location', '$scope'];
    function ProductController($http, $location, $rootScope, $scope, $localStorage, $interval, $timeout,$mdDialog, $document, shareBtwnCtrlr){
        var vm = this;  
     }
})();
```

Comment: Why not use the `$rootScope.test` in the other controller ?

Comment: you are using strict mode and you didn't declare `shareBtwnCtrlr` using `var` . This can raise error

Comment: @SaneeshB here i am using two controller, the first controller executed first at that time  $scope.value shows result as undefined after second controller executed the result stored but i couldn't get that result in first controller.

Answer (score 0):

You got two modules, so dependency injector can't inject your service from app.core to app.product. 
Try to create new module

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.core','app.product']);
```

and then

```
angular.module('app').factory('shareBtwnCtrlr', shareBtwnCtrlrService);
```

Comment: But last time i have used fileUploader service. Like i had injected from app.core to app.message module it was working nicely.

Comment: Is it a service, declared in your module? Or just an another module (3rd party library) you injected to your module?

Comment: ha it is a service

Comment: Can You show the code of this? Because a service declared in "module1" can be injected to "module2" only by injecting "module1" to "module2" or by injecting "module1" and "module2" to "module3"

Comment: `(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core')
        .factory('fileUploader', fileUploadService);

    /** @ngInject */
    function fileUploadService($resource,$http) {
   var fileUploader = {};
    fileUploader.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){

  return fileUploader;
    }
})();`

Comment: And what did you inject to `app.message` module?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113992/discussion-between-e-abrakov-and-kevin).

Comment: i haven't injected anything to app.message module, but i have injected 'fileUploader' to message controller like   function MessageController($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope, fileUploader)

Answer (score 0):

Only a service in the same module can be injected to the controllers and directives of the module.

The new module should be added to the app to expand its capabilities.

```
angular.module('app.core')
 .factory('shareBtwnCtrlrService', function() {
    var shareBtwnCtrlrService = this;

    shareBtwnCtrlrService.value = function(){
        //do something
    }

    return shareBtwnCtrlrService;
 }
};

 angular.module('app.product')
 .factory('productService', function() {
    var productService = this;

    productService.value = function(){
        //do something
    }

    return productService;
 }
};
```

Now to use the service in the `core` and `product` modules, we create `app` module including both in it

```
angular.module('app', ['app.product', 'app.core'])
 .controller('ProductController', ['shareBtwnCtrlrService', 'productService', function (shareBtwnCtrlrService, productService) {
     // ...do something
 }]);
```